# Pkcs11Interop CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID exception cause high CPU usage

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, hsm, pkcs11interop

We are using `Pkcs11Interop` library for cryptography and we customize&implement `Pkcs11Interop` code samples for our project where `Pkcs11Interop` documents in [Github](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/doc/CODE_SAMPLES.md). In production, not everyday but we have to restart server after CPU usage reach maximum when we get a consecutive(4 or 5 times) `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID` exception. What cause this ? How can we fix this problem ? Any ideas will be appreciated. If anyone want I can share our code sample. Thanks for helping.

> 2017-07-11 10:45:07,580 ERROR HSM | 11.07.2017 10:45:07 | HSM Decrypt
>   error occured Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.Pkcs11Exception: Method
>   C_Decrypt returned CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID at
>   Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI41.Session.Decrypt(Mechanism mechanism,
>   ObjectHandle keyHandle, Byte[] encryptedData)    at
>   Pkcs11HsmHost.DecryptInSession(Session session, String value, Int32 keyIndex, Int32 retryCount) in Security\Pkcs11HsmHost.cs:line 164

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not using your PKCS#11 library correctly in miltithreaded environment. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43210552/3325704) for more info.

Comment: Hi Jariq,
We prepared a sample project and implement your code samples where publish in github. But we found something weird, there is no AppType in Pkcs11 Library. 

"If an application will be accessing PKCS#11 library from multiple threads simultaneously, it should specify "AppType.MultiThreaded" as a value of "appType" parameter. PKCS#11 library will use the native operation system threading model for locking."

Comment: @MuratGündeş `AppType` enum is available only in current master branch which is yet to be released as new major version 4.0. In older versions this setting uses `bool` type so you need to set it to `true`.

Comment: And another one is, GetSlotList method. Your sample is like below,
List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent);

But we didn't find anything about SlotsType like AppType. When we check the GetSlotList method, it takes a parameter named bool tokenPresent.

Comment: @MuratGündeş you need to work with samples and documentation in [3.3.0 branch](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/tree/3.3.0) instead of [master branch](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop)